# showing custom tooltip for Discrete chart using nvd3

Tags: nvd3.js

I am looking for help to override default **tooltip** functionality for **nvd3 bar (discrete) chart**.

The default tooltip picks yAxis ticks and show in the tooltip.

However, in my case i don't want to show yAxis data (formatted in currency) in tooltip rather than i would like show actual yAxis value (original value without currency).

This is how i am pushing values to my data[].

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BarChart)
  {
    string yvalue = item.Cost== 0 ? "undefined" : item.Cost.ToString();
    string xvalue = item.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    @:data[0].values.push({y: @yvalue, x: '@xvalue'});
  }
```

I am formatting yAxis tick using the following line of code

```
chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(".1s")(d) + " USD" });
```

Any hint?
Let me know if you need more info?

After googling, i found the following way but in this example **'y'** is yAxis value and not the original value. So, how i can replace this 'y' with orginal value?

```
chart.tooltip(function (key, x, y, e, graph) {
                return '<p><strong>' + key + '</strong></p>' +
                '<p>' + y + ' in the month ' + x + '</p>';
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `e.value` instead of `y`.

```
chart.tooltipContent(function (key, x, y, e, graph) {
    return '<p><strong>' + key + '</strong></p>' +
           '<p>' + e.value + ' in the month ' + x + '</p>';
    });
```

`e.point` should also contain the original data, including any extra attributes. For example, if your input data has an "extra" attribute (like `{ label : "A" , value : -29.76, extra: 123 }`), then you can use `e.point.extra`.

Comment: It works with e.value  but not with e.y. I guess you also meant to use e.value and not e,y because y contains formatted data. Right?

Comment: Good catch, I didn't get the data format quite right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Just a heads up, the tooltipContent function will be deprecated in the next release because the tooltip code has been rewritten. You'll have to use the new tooltip.contentGenerator() function in the future.

Comment: I'm getting undefined for chart.tooltipContent ..??